# How do I import my wallet.dat file into a new wallet?

Tags: wallet, backup, wallet.dat, wallet-import

I have my wallet.dat backup file, but Bitcoin Core isn't able to verify it. How do I retrieve my backup?

Comment: So you placed the wallet.dat in the correct folder and then tried to re-scan? Whats the exact error you receive?

Comment: Asker has not clarified his question after nearly two months – putting it on hold for unclear what is asked.